# GridView with 4 items android

Tags: java, android, gridview, uiimageview

I'm trying to make a gridview because thats better for more devices. I already tried to add my buttons in the interface builder (as ImageViews because I've added them as ImageButtons the size wasn't good) and the result of that is in this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRkYd.png

Can anyone help me by making this in a GridView, just exactly the same but compatible on all the devices.

Thanks in advance ;)!

This is the ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] buttonValues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] buttonValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.buttonValues = buttonValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);


        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        String button = buttonValues[position];



        if (button.equals("homework")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.homework);
        } else if (button.equals("schedule")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.schedulebut);
        } else if (button.equals("planner")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plannerbut);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.settingsbut);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttonValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

and this is my method in the onCreate :

```
static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Homework", "Schedule",
        "Planner", "Settings" };
private void setGridView() {
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOL!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to use a **2X2 Grid** and have only 4 elements, use **`android:numColumns="2"`** as an attribute of your GridView.

Additionally, there is this excellent [tutorial on GridViews](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)!

Code snippet to implement only Images in your Grid :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;


    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);


            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);



            if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windows_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobiles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**EDIT :** You are getting the same image in all the buttons because you are matching the strings which you have written in different cases. (You are using *"Homework"* in one place and *"homework"* in another)

So, use `static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "homework", "schedule", "planner", "settings" };` and it would work fine.

Comment: That tutorial only gives examples with text and text&images. I only need images any more tutorials?

Comment: You can still follow this tutorial. Just remove the TextView from each of the child elements and you would get only the images.

Comment: Okay I tried another tutorial this morning but when I used that my 'buttons' were resized and not in the good size. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Yeah since you are forcing a 2*2 layout, the images would be resized to fit according to the screen. You can just let it set the number of columns and rows itself automatically, or you can include images for different resolutions in your `drawable` folder.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code to show only images. Rest is same as the tutorial that I gave you.

Comment: Check my edited answer, I tried it that way but if I test my app, I don't see any images/buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23050/discussion-between-wouterdz-and-swayam)

Comment: I now have 4 the same buttons instead of 4 different

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning different images to each of them properly ? Could you please post your code ? I would have a look at it.

Comment: Ofcourse but isn't it easier to start something like a private chat.

Comment: Well, I believe if you post your code in the question, it will be seen by everyone and you will get more help incase I am not able to solve your problem.

Comment: And you are getting which button image in all four buttons ?

Comment: Found the mistake. You are not matching the cases properly. Use `static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "homework", "schedule",
        "planner", "settings" };
`

Comment: Thanks it worked! Now I only need to set the onClickListeners with pressed buttons I made myself, how could I implement them easily! Again thank you very much you helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get fixed sizes you can add

android:layout_height=""
 android:layout_width=""

example :

android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:layout_width="200dp"

in your button tags

Comment: Thanks, but I define my buttons in Java not in XML so maybe I could give my GridView certain sizes?